# How to join employees to orders?

Tags: mysql, join

I am simply not understanding joins very well at all!

My exercise calls for:

> Display the employee’s last name and first name, city, country and ship city for orders where the employees live in the city where the order is delivered.

I have started my answer thus far here:

```
SELECT
Employees.LastName,
Employees.FirstName,
Employees.City,
Employees.Country,
Orders.ShipCity
FROM
Employees,
Orders
```

But then I realise that I am stuck and do not know where to go from here. Do I need to find a table that has common entries in both in order to find primary keys and foreign keys? What is my solution here?

For reference, here is an image of where I am taking data from for my solutions:

[image]

Comment: There are two things to do here, I think: firstly join these two tables using their 1:many relation (i.e. PK in one to FK in the other). Do that first, would you give that a go? Refer to MySQL examples on the web if you want to see how to do joins directly. Do not worry about `for orders where the employees live in the city where the order is delivered` to start with.

Comment: Thanks mate. That's what I thought was my first step, but my train of thought (which I'm guessing is wrong) was that I need to find one of the options in one table that is reflected in the other. So I need to find something from Employees that is in Orders, or vice versa. Is that correct? If so, am I going blind or do none of the things I need to produce (fname, last etc etc) carry across both?

Comment: Once you have done that then you will have just the last constraint to add, and it can be added as a `WHERE` clause [due to a connection hiccup this was written at the same time as my first comment, and has only just posted].

Comment: `I need to find one of the options in one table that is reflected in the other`, well, you need to do that as well, but that's your second step. Do the first step first. Do you know how to do joins?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
Employees.LastName,
Employees.FirstName,
Employees.City,
Employees.Country,
Orders.ShipCity
FROM
Employees  inner join Orders 
    on Employees.EmployeeID= Orders.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but that seems to give me an error message "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Employee.EmployeeID' in 'on clause'"

Comment: Man I write the Table name wrong. please write Employees instead of Employee

Comment: Haha thank you man! Do you know how I need to do this part - " orders where the employees live in the city where the order is delivered."? How do I word the WHERE?